# Page Formatting Lost When Using GiHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When I compile my jekyll site and test locally using "jekyll serve" all is fine. But when github compiles it and host it my site looses all formatting. What should I do to prevent this or trobuleshoot this ?

**Locally Hosted (Jekyll Serve) - Good**
[image: Local Site (Good)]
**GiHub Hosted (Jekyll) - Lost Formatting, Moved to Left **
[image: Remote Site (Bad)]

Comment: Have you check your source code, may be styling is missing. What's URL?

Comment: It works perfectly when use "jekyll serve" locally [link](https://sachin-gupta.github.io/)

Comment: See your [stylesheet is missing](https://sachin-gupta.github.io/assets/main.css). Can you please put your head section where you link the style. I mean what you're using like prepend baseurl or something like that.

Comment: Hi goyllo, when i clean build site on my machine, in _site\assets\ folder main.css stylesheet is generated and page is properly styled on localhost. As _site is root location of stylesheet should be "https://sachin-gupta.github.io/assets/main.css" which is perfect in index.html. Please advice ?

Comment: You're hosting your _site folder, why? Host only other directories. Github pages will build your site for you.

Comment: Sir, not hosting _site this is in exclusion of .gitignore. Am shocked, what could be the reason that stylesheet "sachin-gupta.github.io/assets/main.css" went not accessible - is it that its not getting generate by jekyll on github server :(

Comment: I don't know why your blog post contain _post folder, because it is always ignore by jekyll. Are you sure, your blog permalink as same as in localhost. I doubt you host it differently. Give me your github repository URL.

Comment: Sir jekyll picks all posts a .md markups from _posts file thus its present in the code. I am not sure of any tool which can do a postmortem of any code as "suitable for jekyll github" deployment. Thanks for valuable comments, am still working to see why stylesheets are not lifted by jekyll. It could be that github compiler is not generating assets/main.css

Comment: Do one thing. Go to your _site folder, get the css file and name it style.css and paste it in css folder like this, css/style.css and link that file in head section. It generally don't use pre processor. And If Github don't generate your site, then they message you in your email. It is automatic process, and when they failed to build any site then, they inform to all people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the file is at https://sachin-gupta.github.io/css/main.css

/assets/main.scss does not exist, so what source file would be generating https://sachin-gupta.github.io/assets/main.css? Have you committed everything?

Comment: Yes, file is there - local site generation works fine

Comment: what source file would be generating https://sachin-gupta.github.io/assets/main.css?

Comment: main.scss in css folder, when we create new jekyll project in a folder lets say "myfldr" it creates this file which importa minima theme by default

Comment: /css/main.css is the source for /css/main.css, not /assets/main.css

Comment: "css/main.scss" a scss file gets compiled into "assets/main.css" locally with jekyll. This file import theme named "minima" so site works well locally. Now am not sure and able to find why this file is missing from GitHub. I don't think bypassing jekyll and committing entire _site folder (locally generated) would be a good idea. Main idea is why this file missing in github and how to make it appear inside "_site\assets\main.css?

Comment: Thanks to all for helping, I've found a bypass (i've committed locally generated main.css from main.scss into new folder assets, so this gets copied into final github site).